# is it correct "go off" is "stop liking something"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm learning English with my favorite singers song.
when I was listening to Taylor Swift' song "you belong with me" , I could not understand a part of it's song.

This song has lyrics like below.

"
You’re on the phone with your girlfriend, she’s upset
She’s going off about something that you said
"

unknown point is "going off".
I tried to appreciate this meaning with a [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-off).
it taught me the "go off" is stop liking something, so changed the lyrics to "she stop like something that you said"
but after change of it , I felt something is wrong for it...
is it correct "going off" is "stop like something"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrasal verb 'go off' has a number of meanings ([list here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-off)), and I would choose this one:

> INTRANSITIVE
> ​AMERICAN​
> INFORMAL
> to suddenly become angry and
> start shouting

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-off#go-off__19)

Comment: ... like a rocket :)

Comment: Or a bomb, volcano, firework, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You say the song has lyrics “like” below, which means it is similar to but not exactly the same as below. Nevertheless, I assume that you mean the lyrics are exactly as shown below. The phrase “going off” then probably means that she is complaining forcefully about what was said. It parallels “sounding off”, which is when someone talks forcefully about something.

Your dictionary is incomplete. It is only giving you the other meaning. “My girlfriend is going off me” means she does not like me as much as she used to. “She has gone off me” means she used to like me but now does not